# c# ways to create the object

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class a(){
  public void test(){
       console.writeline("test");
  }
}

public class b(){
  public void test(){
       console.writeline("test");
  }
}

public class main(){
  a testa =new a();
  b testb = testa as b //<=
}
```

So will this statement mark with indicator (<=) will execute ? If possible also tell whats the purpose and advantages of using it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile and the error described by the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYHUUe) provided by user @SamiKuhome is actually hugely descriptive as to why.

> Cannot convert type 'a' to 'b' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null reference conversion

The compiler has no idea how to convert between type `a` and `b` as there is no relationship between the classes.

To answer your question: "If possible also tell whats the purpose and advantages of using it?"

Establish a relationship between the two classes `a` and `b`.
Let's assume that class `b` is a specification of class `a`:

```
public class a 
{
    public void test()
    {
        console.writeline("test");
    }
}

public class b extends a // note change, here
{
    public void test()
    {
       console.writeline("test");
   }
}
```

#### Classifications

It is easiest to consider groups of classes;

You might have a class `c` that also `extends a`. Both `b` and `c` then would be considered to have `a` in *common*. In the real world, we see this modeled by scientific fields (and this is where the word "class" comes from: classification): something might be an "animal" (`a`), but that isn't very descriptive. To further specify what type of animal we are dealing with (in this case, `b` and `c` - maybe a dolphin and cat).

All of these animals might share something in common: This would be considered a trait of `a`.

#### Rules of Using Classification

Programming languages are pretty opinionated about how classifications can work with each other to describe a relationship. Your code may not compile in other languages (if the above relationship was maintained) and - at the very least - would generate a warning.

Why?

When code is working with an object or instance of `a`, it only wants to interact with - or is only contracted to work with - that particular type. All the compiler knows is that type `a` is type `a`.

Casting to *a more specific* type is generally considered dangerous (that doesn't mean it isn't done).

Both `b` and `c` satisfy `a` requirements - they both share the classification; however, at runtime, we can't be sure that every instance of `a` that we encounter is indeed a particular specification. We may see both `b` and `c`. And - as we can imagine - forcing a dolphin to be a cat isn't particular meaningful (or really possible).

If you want to read more about the motivations behind these concepts, look at [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).